# Create lags relative to whole change within group

Tags: r, lag, dplyr

I've tried creating a variable that represents the lagged version of another variable relative to the whole change of the variable within the group.

Let's use this example dataframe:

```
game_data <- data.frame(player = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), level = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), score=as.numeric(c(0,150,170,80,100,110,75,100,0)))
game_data
  player level score
1      1     1     0
2      1     2   150
3      1     3   170
4      2     1    80
5      2     2   100
6      2     3   110
7      3     1    75
8      3     2   100
9      3     3     0
```

I've tried the following, but while lagging the variable works, I am not able to create a new variable that shows the lag of the variable relative to the whole change for the player:

```
result <- 
+   game_data %>%
+   group_by(player) %>%
+   mutate(
+     lag_score = score - dplyr::lag(score, n=1, default = NA),
+     lag_score_relative = lag_score/sum(lag_score))

result
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   player [3]
  player level score lag_score lag_score_relative
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>              <dbl>
1      1     1     0        NA                 NA
2      1     2   150       150                 NA
3      1     3   170        20                 NA
4      2     1    80        NA                 NA
5      2     2   100        20                 NA
6      2     3   110        10                 NA
7      3     1    75        NA                 NA
8      3     2   100        25                 NA
9      3     3     0      -100                 NA
```

For example, for player 1 it should be in
Level 1: NA/170 = NA
Level 2: 150/170
Level 3: 20/170

Thanks in advance, I hope anyone can help.

Comment: What do you expect the lag_score_relative to be for player 2 and 3?

Comment: I think that the `NA` lag values break everything when you get the `sum`. Try using `na.rm=T`

Comment: Player 2: level 2: 20/30, level 3: 10/30
Player 3: level 2: 25/125, level 3: -(100/125)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `sum` the lagged scores you include an `NA`. The `sum` then returns `NA`. You divide by `NA` which in the end returns `NA` for every value. To avoid this just set the `na.rm` argument to `TRUE` in your call of `sum` and `NA`s do not get included in the sum:

```
game_data <- data.frame(player = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), level = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), 
  score=as.numeric(c(0,150,170,80,100,110,75,100,0)))
   game_data %>%
   group_by(player) %>%
 mutate(
   lag_score = score - dplyr::lag(score, n=1, default = NA),
   lag_score_relative = lag_score/sum(lag_score, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: This works perfectly and it semms logic R can't compute with NA, thank you!